# MongoDB Query:I can't get the result object outside the scope of the callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using express API connected to MongoDB and when I query the DB to get the result, I can use them only within the scope of the callback and even I assign the value of the result to a globally declared variable, when using console.log(), the result is undefined

here is my code

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const express = require('express');
const assert = require('assert');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT||13000;



app.get('/',(req,res) => {

        let myIncomingData;

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
        MongoClient.connect(url,{useNewUrlParser:true},(err,db)=>{
        assert.equal(err,null);
        db.db('my_posts').collection('posts').find().toArray((err,result) =>{
         assert.equal(err,null);
         console.log(result);       // here the result gets printed 
         myIncomingData = result;
        }); // db.collection
   db.close();



        }); // MongoClient.connect
        console.log(myIncomingData);  //  print undefined  why ??
}) // app.get


app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log('server is running ...'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node is asynchronous, so at the time that you're doing the `console.log`, `myIncomingData` is still undefined (you can even see this by the order of the `console.logs` -- first it will log that undefined from that second `console.log` and then it will log the `console.log` that's in the callback). If you wanted to see this in action, you could try doing something like `setTimeout(() => console.log(myIncomingData), 5 * 1000)` -- by delaying 5 seconds, you can be pretty sure that the callback code will have run, and if you want to do anything further with that value, you'll need to do it from within the callback (either inline or by calling another function)

[`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) can make code like this easier to read and reason about. If you want to continue using callbacks, it'd be worth taking a look at a callback tutorial to make sure you understand what's going on with them.

Comment: just to be clear, you _shouldn't_ be using `setTimeout` to fix the problem -- I was just using that to illustrate what the problem is

Comment: yeah I understand but also I when I used the promise and I made the result object returned through the resolve() , also it still async , i think I'd better to use async/await to do that,      the setTimeout made it clear for me that it is just a matter of time and the incomingData will get their value from the result object @willis